# $R$ is a partial order on nonempty finite set $S$, does $S$ contain an element $b$ such that if $aRb$ implies $a = b$

Tags: relations

I do not know how to start.
I tried to use property of transitive and reflexive to get $bRa$, but i cannot connect those together. Any hint on how to prove this?

Comment: sorry about the formatting...

Comment: The secret of formatting here is that you should think about the dollar signs as some sort of brackets: everything you want to look 'mathematical' should be *in between* dollars, not just preceded by a dollar

Comment: removed?...............

Comment: Do mean some b such that for all a, ( bRa implies a = b)?

Comment: @WilliamElliot yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### After question edit

If $|S|=1$ the statement is obvious. Now let's do full induction.

Suppose the statement holds for every nonempty partially ordered set with less than $|S|$ elements.

Let $a\in S$ and consider $T=\{x\in S:xRa, x\ne a\}$. If $T$ is empty, you are done. Otherwise, $|T|<|S|$ and so the induction hypothesis apply.

Now finish up the argument.

---

### Original answer

You are asking whether any infinite partially ordered set has a minimal element.

Since total orders are partial orders, the property would imply that every infinite totally ordered set has a minimum. Now, can you find a counterexample?

Comment: I cannot. But how would you prove that infinite partially ordered set has a minimal value.

Comment: @B.LIANG You can't prove a false statement. Take the integers, for instance.

Comment: Sorry, I actually want to focus on finite set. That's a typo in the question...

Comment: @B.LIANG OK, answer edited

Comment: Thank you. Solve that with proof by contradiction.

Comment: @B.LIANG No contradiction: $T$ inherits the partial order and has less elements than $S$; by the induction hypothesis, it has a minimal element. $m$; suppose $b\in S$ and $bRm$; then $bRa$ by transitivity and $b\ne a$, otherwise $m=a$; thus $b\in T$ and therefore $b=m$ by minimality.

Answer (score 0):

Try it out on order $(\mathbb R,\leq)$.

Then you will find that no such element $b\in\mathbb R$ exists.

Simply because $a:=b-1\leq b$ and $a\neq b$ for every $b\in\mathbb R$.